ScalaFX and Cats Effect
I am trying to integrate Cats Effect into a ScalaFX desktop application, and I am having trouble getting the tasks to execute. I would like to run a background thread/fiber to initialize the window when it is displayed. What I THINK I'm doing is:

Starting the JavaFX application on a blocking IO.
JavaFX is doing a bunch of stuff, including starting its own threads and stuff. I am not sure if this matters.
On the "JavaFX Application Thread" thread, the controller's initializable method is running (confirmed with the println), and creating the IO I would like to execute.
I am creating the Supervisor to execute it in the background.
It is not printing "Hello".

I've tried a few solutions, like calling SupervisorIO.evalOn() instead of the simple call below. I've tried calling "join" on the thread created by Supervisor#supervise to try and force it to execute, and nothing is happening.
I simplified the application to look like this (the FXML is just a BorderPane and a Label and it configures the controller class; I didn't think you'd need to see it):
object CatsTest extends IOApp.Simple {
  override def run: IO[Unit] = {
    IO.blocking {
      Application.launch(classOf[CatsTestMain])
    }
  }
}

class CatsTestMain extends Application {
  override def start(primaryStage: Stage): Unit = {
    val screen = getClass.getResource("/main-screen.fxml")
    val loader = new FXMLLoader()
    loader.setLocation(screen)
    val root: Parent = loader.load[javafx.scene.Parent]
    val controller = loader.getController[MainController]()

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new javafx.scene.Scene(root)))
    primaryStage.show()
  }
}

class MainController extends Initializable {
  override def initializable(location: URL, resources: ju.ResourceBundle): Unit = {
    println("in controller")
    val supervisor = Supervisor[IO](await=true)
    supervisor.use { supervisor =>
      supervisor.supervise(IO.println("Hello"))
    }
  }
}

I don't know if I need to marshal back into the original thread to use Cats' resources, or what is the problem. I'm new to Cats Effect, and this was the first application I've written in a while that wasn't bound to use Akka/Pekko, so it seemed like a good way to learn it, but I can't help but think I've created more problems than I've solved not just using Future objects.
ANSWER:
The final code that prints "In controller" and then "Hello" is below. In CatsTest.run, by creating the Dispatcher Resource and then calling "use", it created an IO to hand up to the IOApp that it could run. This IO creates a factory method that has access to the dispatcher and then creates a blocking IO from which to launch the JavaFX application defined in CatsTestMain. (I suppose the CATS-way to do this would be to put the first part in one IO and chain that to the blocking IO). The JavaFX application then uses the controller factory method defined above in the FXMLLoader to pass the dispatcher to the Controller class so that it can be used by the window controller. After this, JavaFX calls Initializable#initialize on the controller and prints out "In controller", and then the dispatcher can be used to execute an IO.
object CatsTest extends IOApp.Simple {
  var factory: javafx.util.Callback[Class[?], Object] = null

  override def run: IO[Unit] = {
    Dispatcher.sequential[IO] use { dispatcher =>
      factory = { (tpe: Class[?]) => 
        if(classOf[MainController].isAssignableFrom(tpe)) {
          tpe.newInstance().asInstanceOf[MainController].dispatcherOpt = Some(dispatcher)
        } else {
          tpe.newInstance()
        }
      }
      IO.blocking { Application.launch(classOf[CatsTestMain]) }
    }
  }
}

class CatsTestMain extends Application {
  override def start(primaryStage: Stage): Unit = {
    ... the stuff above to initialize the loader
    loader.setControllerFactory(CatsTest.factory)
    ... the rest of the stuff to create and show the stage
  }
}

class MainController extends Intializable {
  var dispatcherOpt: Option[Dispatcher[IO]] = None

  override def intialize(location: URL, resources: ju.ResourceBundle): Unit = {
    println("In controller")
    dispatcherOpt.map(dispatcher => {
      dispatcher.unsafeRunAndForget(IO.println("Hello"))
    })
  }


The method in the Initializable interface is initialize() (not initializable()). So it's likely your controller method is not being called at all. I don't know the library you are using (or, indeed, Scala), but it looks like the Supervisor constructor is a blocking call. You must not make blocking calls on the FX Application Thread.

That feels extremely convoluted even for Java standards.

@James_D, moving blocking calls of the FX Application Thread is the goal. This is just a single-purpose tool I use at work that I hack on to learn new things, so this project is a follow-up to this question at Scala Users https://users.scala-lang.org/t/using-with-a-future/9887/6 . I finally found time to try Cats Effects instead of the Future-based solution I used there.

There are two problems here:
The first and most important one is that supervisor.use returns an IO, which is just a description of a computation, nothing more. It needs to be explicitly run or sequenced with other IOs. This is the fundamental knowledge needed to write cats-effect applications, IO are just descriptions, values, not handlers of a running computation; contrary to Future
What you want to use for this kind of interop is a Dispatcher, not a Supervisor: https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/api/3.x/cats/effect/std/Dispatcher.html that gives you a unsafeRunAndForget to send the IO to run in the background.
Second, you are doing a bad management of the life cycle. You don't want to create and destroy one Dispatcher per IO to execute. Ideally MainController should receive an already allocated Dispatcher and something else must ensure it is properly closed when not needed anymore.
Third, if the IOs you plan to run will affect the interface, those need to run on the appropriate threads of JavaFX.


so it seemed like a good way to learn it

Personally, I would disagree.

First, IO is better suited for web servers that have to deal with concurrency.
Second, these kinds of apps that require bidirectional interop are actually harder to write for a newcomer. Because they expect you to be proficient in both JavaFX internals and cats-effect execution model.

Having said that. A lot of folks have built similar things during the last years. You may ask in the Discord servers for advice and resources.

I tried the example here: https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/std/dispatcher, but Dispatcher.sequential[IO] returns a Resource, not a Dispatcher, and that dispatcher.use { .. } returns an IO, so it's turtles all the way down. I don't get it. I know that an IO is a description of function, but I can't get it to go.
I'll worry about lifecycle when it works.
I know how to pass data into the JavaFX thread; I'm not worried about that.

@JonathanCard yeah that is what I mean with "MainController should receive an already allocated Dispatcher". Ask for a plain Dispatcher[IO] on the constructor of that class. Ideally who constructs MainController would also ask for a plain Dispatcher all the way up to main where you can use the Resource and provide a proper IO for run. However, if that is not viable, then you can use allocated on the Resource and then use unsafeRunSync to run the creation of the Dispatcher. - You may also just ditch Dispatcher altogether and just use one of the unsafeRun methods

@JonathanCard Note that you can pass a parameter to the constructor of a controller either by 1. omitting fx:controller="..." in the FXML, creating the controller in code, and passing it to fxmlLoader.setController(...) before calling fxmlLoader.load(), or by 2. specifying a controllerFactory on the FXMLLoader which specifies how to construct the controller.

OMG, I will never understand why Java tools need to make simple stuff like constructors and argument passing such a PITA. Anyways, @JonathanCard given what James said, I would say that the best thing you can do is just use the unsafeRun methods directly on the IO you want to run. Or create the Dispatcher inside the constructor or initialization of MainController but who knows if that may have some adverse effect on JavaFX.

I didn't see your comments here until I'd worked through the details and then edited my answer to include the working code. Thank you for your help.

:) And Scalafx has some better use patterns for working with JavaFX, but they only work with Scala 2.13, so that's another way I made things more difficult for myself.

@JonathanCard ScalaFX does support Scala 3: https://github.com/scalafx/scalafx/releases/tag/v.22.0.0-R33

You are right; I mis-spoke. I meant vigoo/ScalaFXML https://github.com/vigoo/scalafxml, which is what does the dependency injection stuff. The last I saw, that didn't work with Scala 3 macros.
